# ResolveRoom API throws ValidationException error in Alexa For Business API

Tags: python-3.x, api, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-for-business

I am working on the Alexa For Business API's in python.When i am using the ResolveRoom API i am getting the error which is

> "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ResolveRoom operation: User ID is invalid, for a different skill or does not currently have room information associated with it"

I have created the private skill and published to my Alexa For Business Account.I am passing the same private skill id and User id which is taken from skill request.

UserId looks like "amzn1.ask.account.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX".Got from the below session request.

Request session:

```
"session": {
"new": false,
"sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"application": {
"applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX"
},
"user": {
"userId": "amzn1.ask.account.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
}
```

Python:

```
response = client_a4b.resolve_room( UserId="amzn1.ask.account.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
SkillId='amzn1.ask.skill.XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX'
)
```

But i am getting the ValidationException error.I tried with Alexa For Business Userid,UserArn and got same error. How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever I am doing is correct.The problem is **Alexa For Business** supports only US device now.Which one I am testing was UK.

When I test with US device it works like charm.